# Cordova onresume event not working/firing on Android 4.0.3

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, onresume

Here is my event handler code:

```
//
function onResume() {
    console.log( 'on resume' );  
}

//
function onDeviceReady(){  
  document.addEventListener( "pause", function(){console.log('on pause');}, false);
  document.addEventListener( "resume", onResume, false);
}

//
function onLoad() {
  document.addEventListener( "deviceready", onDeviceReady, false );  
}
```

I have tried weinre and Android ddms tools for troubleshooting but did not see the "on resume" msg logged on console when I switch between apps during testing on the device. Pause event is working fine however and logging messages.

I am also seeing the underlying on resume events getting called but my event handler for some reason does not get called. Here is what I see in logs.

```
06-30 23:49:50.500: I/CordovaLog(6118): Found start page location: index.html
06-30 23:49:50.500: D/CordovaActivity(6118): Resuming the App
06-30 23:49:50.500: D/CordovaActivity(6118): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null
06-30 23:49:50.510: D/CordovaActivity(6118): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
06-30 23:49:50.610: D/CordovaActivity(6118): onMessage(spinner,stop)
```

FYI: Code works fine on iOS simulator.

Any ideas why this may be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: As per the API [link here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html) docs. **When called from a resume event handler, interactive functions such as alert() need to be wrapped in a setTimeout() call with a timeout value of zero, or else the app hangs.** Try to use a the function in a setTimeout() call and see if it works.

Comment: I have tried that too but didn't work ... it also works on iOS simulator and works on Android when I press power button while app is running in foreground and unlock the screen then resume event gets fired.